# Why is this vanishing set nowhere dense?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative ring and $f\in A$ be a nonzerodivisor.

Why is $\mathrm{V}(f)$ nowhere dense in $\mathrm{Spec(A)}$?

Edit: This question has been closed because it lacks context and motivation. I try to provide it here. Back when I asked the question, I was a beginner in the field of algebraic geometry, and didn't have enough intuition in the subject to see the right approach. Of course, this is a very basic question in algebraic geometry, and a good exercise for a beginner of the field to learn how to combine geometric intuition and algebraic rigor, which in my opinion should be reason enough to discuss this question here.

Comment: While the question lacks motivation, a beginner in the subject might have trouble piecing the definitions to prove it. There is a good answer posted here by the user Captain Lama. So I don't see the need for this question to be closed.

Comment: I find it a bit disconcerting that one has to justify very clearly formulated questions which are at the core of certain mathematical fields. Isn't that motivation/context enough, or why has this to be stated explicitly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose $V(f)$ has non-empty interior ; then since the principal open sets are a basis of the topology, there is $g\in A$ not nilpotent such that $D(g)\subset V(f)$.

This means that $Spec(A_{(g)}/(f)) = Spec(A_{(g)})$, so $f$ is nilpotent in $A_{(g)}$. Now by definition of localization, this means that $g^nf^m=0$ for some $m,n\in \mathbb{N}$, and $f$ is a zero-divisor.

Comment: I think instead of $f=0$ in $A_g$, we only get $f\in\mathfrak{N}$, but this solves the problem nonetheless. Thanks!

Comment: Ah yes you're right.

Comment: Also, we should choose $g\in A\backslash\mathfrak{N}$ to make sure that $g^n$ isn't zero itself.